# Reactor.run freezes loop

Tags: python, twisted

I have a Twisted socket that I am attempting to run on multiple ports. The following code has worked for me before, but that was around 1 month ago as I have not touched the code since, if I remember right. Now, after re-entering the code into my Twisted program, it doesn't work anymore.

```
class Socket(Protocol):
    table = Table()

    def connectionMade(self):
        #self.transport.write("""connected""")
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "Clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        #print "data is ", data
        a = data.split(':')
        if len(a) > 1:
            command = a[0]
            content = a[1]

            if command == "Number_of_Players":
                msg = table.numberOfPlayers


        print msg

        for c in self.factory.clients:
                c.message(msg)

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message)

NUM_TABLES = 10

factories = [ ]
for i in range(0, NUM_TABLES):
    print i
    factory = Factory()
    factory.protocol = Socket
    factory.clients = []
    factories.append(factory)
    reactor.listenTCP(1025+i, factory)
    #print "Blackjack server started"
    reactor.run()
```

It would usually print Blackjack server started however many times in the range I set, but now it doesn't. To test if it was looping over or not, I set out to print i, but it only printed 0. For some reason, the for loop only looped 1 time.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: does reactor.run() have a loop in it? It would be my guess that it does, as it isnt allowing it to pass past there.

Comment: @Levon It printed 9 for everything, then once reactor.run() was uncommented, it only printed 0.

Comment: @PsychicOak What do you mean if run has a loop in it?

Comment: What i mean is that it may be running a loop inside of reactor.run() and therefor the for loop is not continuing because it is waiting for reactor.run() to finish.

Comment: The thing is, this code has worked before. Why not now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twisted programs usually have only one `reactor` running. Keep in mind that when you start (`.run()`) the reactor, execution passes inside the reactor loop (and the various events that you have defined in your code, like `connectionMade()`, `connectionLost()`, `dataReceived()`, etc are triggered when the respective actions take place). Whatever code is after the `reactor.run()` is executed only **after reactor is stopped**.

So, your code never passes the first iteration of the `for` loop.

Try moving the `reactor.run()` out of the loop:

```
NUM_TABLES = 10

factories = [ ]
for i in range(0, NUM_TABLES):
    print i
    factory = Factory()
    factory.protocol = Socket
    factory.clients = []
    factories.append(factory)
    reactor.listenTCP(1025+i, factory)

# print "Blackjack server started"

reactor.run()

# whatever code you put here, is executed only **after reactor has stopped**
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just keep looping over the settings of everything in the loop and not even run the reactor?

Comment: It would loop (10 times) and then start the reactor (once).

Comment: I just did it, and the loop goes from 0 to 9 and I connected to port 1025, and it worked. Connected to 1031, it worked. But now my question is… is ONLY ONE factory running in the reactor and listening on multiple ports, or is reactor running different factories on different ports?

Comment: Your code suggests that you have built 10 factories, one in each port.

Comment: Ok, then I guess this is settled then. I can't believe I didn't even think of moving that line. Thanks ypercube!

Answer (score 2):

Do you get any sort of error message? There's nothing wrong with your basic loop. I'd suggest commenting out all the lines below `print i` and then selectively add them back until the loop stops - that will tell you what is causing the problem (obviously the 2nd print is not a problem)

Perhaps the `listenTCP()` is hanging waiting for a connection?

Or possibly you have some sort of infinite loop in one of the functions you are calling. Only way to be certain w/o seeing the other code is to eliminate possible problems by commenting out suspect code and adding it back in.

**Update**: Based on your new information, the problem obviously is with `reactor.run()`. If the code is self-contained enough you could post it for examination.

Two potential problems in `reactor.code()`, an *infinite* loop, or the program is *waiting* for some sort of *event/input*.

The loop may be infinite, i.e., coded incorrectly so that it starts but never terminates. That would look as if the program is pausing/stopping (even though the CPU is cranking like crazy). Alternatively, the program could pause if it was waiting for some input/event.

Comment: I commented out everything, then uncommented. It printed from 0 to 9 until I uncommented reactor.run(), which only printed 0.

Comment: @AlecK. How big is the code for `reactor.run` .. can you post it? Does it have a loop (possibly infinite accidentally), or is waiting on something?

Comment: +1; I was thinking the same thing, though it's hard to tell without seeing more code.

Comment: I made a connection after the 0 popped up, but nothing else happened besides it said I connected.

Comment: @Levon: You were right in your guess, Twisted is an asychrovous (event-driven) framework. So the "heart" is actualy an infinite loop, that is waiting for events/inputs tp occur. It runs forever or until it's stopped by executing an internal method (`reactor.stop()`).

Answer (score 1):

An exception was thrown before you reached the debugging print.

Catch it by wrapping the shown block with `try: ... except`.

```
try:
       reactor.listenTCP(1025+i, factory)
except IOError as (errno, strerror):
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
except:
    print "something else happened"
```