# Run Reactor.run on Multiple Ports

Tags: python, twisted

I have the following code. I am trying to get reactor to run on the ports starting at 1025 + NUM_TABLES. The issue is that when I call reactor.run() in the loop, the loop freezes. When it is commented, the loop counts from 0 to 9, but when it is uncommented, it only prints 0.

```
NUM_TABLES = 10

factories = [ ]
for i in range(0, NUM_TABLES):
    print i
    factory = Factory()
    factory.protocol = Socket
    factory.clients = []
    factories.append(factory)
    reactor.listenTCP(1025+i, factory)
    #print "Blackjack server started"
    reactor.run()
```

WHat does it take to be able to run a new factory on a different port? Why does reactor stop at 0? It has worked before, why not now? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reactor.run freezes loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866067/reactor-run-freezes-loop)

Comment: Why did you post 2 identical questions?

Comment: This was before I got an answer and was told to post under a different title with a different reason. I got my answer from the other thread, and the paul from this thread said the exact same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't call `reactor.run()` until all of your listeners have been created and registered. It's meant to be the last call you make directly from your main script; everything after that is callbacks.

To clarify, just un-indent the last line one level.

Comment: So I just did it, and the loop goes from 0 to 9 and I connected to port 1025, and it worked. Connected to 1031, it worked. But now my question is… is ONLY ONE factory running in the reactor and listening on multiple ports, or is reactor running different factories on different ports?

Comment: You're creating new Factory objects each time through the loop.

Comment: On different ports right? So port 1025 has a new factory, 1025 has a new factory, etc? They aren't all the same factory just listening on different ports?

Comment: Right, they are different factories attached to different ports.